# Can I sort the extracted line items in datacap based on one of it's field value?

Tags: ibm-datacap

I have extracted line items from a multi-page document. now i require to sort these line items based on Country which is one it's field item. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it using the custom actions, for example by using dictionaries in C#, or similar data structures in other supported languages.